# Create folder on ftp

Tags: c#, ftp

I am using method to create folder on ftp i want get exception if folder already exsists how to make it over write the existing folder

```
using System; using System.Net;

class Test {
    static void Main()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://host.com/directory");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
        }
    } }
```

it is "remote server returned error (550) file not found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "I want to get exception if folder already exists" and "how to make it overwrite the existing folder" are two opposing questions.

At any rate, I just implemented code to do this the other day. Just check if the directory already exists first. And then respond based on that. There's no point in trying to create a directory that already exists.

And if you need to overwrite it somehow, then delete the existing directory before creating the new one.

You can see the code I wrote for this in the article [An FtpClient Class and WinForm Control](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/client/an-ftpclient-class-and-winform-control), although it will just overwrite existing content.

Comment: I don't have access to the code I used right now but I think I used something like WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory and tested for an error. If there was no error, I could assume the directory existed.

Comment: Yes, try to list the directory in try block and if webException.Message.Contains("550") then directory does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider some existing ftp libs out there. I've been using this and have had great success with it.  It's an FTP client library that provides high-level FTP functionality for the FTPrequest in the .NET Framework 2.0.

It has an API for checking if directory exists and for creating the directory.

Code @ http://ftpclient.codeplex.com/

Article @ http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FtpClient.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use this func in solution

```
private void createFolder(string ftpUName, string ftpPWord)
    {
            WebRequest ftpRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://mrhotro.ad/new_sc");
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUName, ftpPWord);
    }
```

Comment: why folder name is not in args?

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite an existing folder... I'm not even sure what benefit that might be.

In short, you need to capture the exception and decide what to do.  Either leave it in place (after all, it already exists...) or you'll need to delete the existing folder and try to recreate it.

I don't remember if you can delete a folder that currently contains files..  If you can't, then you will have to delete those as well.

Comment: Funny that he's reporting that he gets a "file not found" error.

Comment: @Klaus: Yeah, I thought that was a little weird myself